# Find the values of p for which the series is convergent: $p^{\ln(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Please help with 1c. I've gotten a and b, but don't know how to do c. Thank you!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$p^{\ln n} = \exp(\ln n \ln p) = n^{\ln p}$$